# ModuleNotFoundError in Python but the module is there

Tags: python, import

I have a directory called `step_2_my_hand`, and inside it I have 3 python packages; `app.py`, `general_num_and_suit_list.py` and `__init__.py`.

Inside app.py, I have the following:

```
from generate_num_and_suit_list import generate_num_list_from_my_hand

def run_num_list_suit_list():
    num_list, suit_list = generate_num_list_from_my_hand()

    # num list is an integer at this point, and suit list is made up of strings
    return num_list, suit_list
```

And when I run this module directly it works.

In my top level directory, in the same level as the `step_2_my_hand` directory, I have another `app.py`, which contains the following:

```
from all_the_steps_with_coordinates.step_2_my_hand.app import run_num_list_suit_list
```

Now, when I run this, I get the error:

```
...
from generate_num_and_suit_list import generate_num_list_from_my_hand
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'generate_num_and_suit_list'
```

But `generate_num_and_suit_list.py` is a module in the same directory. I checked and there is no spelling mistake.

Comment: How do you execute the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run it in different directory (top-level directory) it will search for `generate_num_and_suit_list` in that (top-level) directory. Try replacing it with:

```
from .generate_num_and_suit_list import generate_num_list_from_my_hand

...
```

Note the `.` that means "this module".